# How make Appendix of paper & number equations in there?

Tags: numbering, appendices

I am making Appendix of my paper, but not sure that my approach is correct. I use the following:

```
\documentclass{12pt}{article}
\begin{document}    
\section*{Appendix A}
 Here comes text.
\begin{equation}
 some formula
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How I can restart numbering of equations and number those as: A.1; A.2, etc?

Comment: The best solution depends on the used `\documentclass`, but many provide a macro `\appendix` that should do this.

Comment: But in general you can set a counter to a specified value by using `\setcounter{<name>}{0}`, e.g., `\setcounter{section}{0}`, and to redefine the way a counter is displayed you can do `\renewcommand\the<name>{<stuff>}`, e.g., `\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you normally would do is use `\appendix` before your appendix start. This changes the section counter to be displayed as uppercase alphabetic and resets it. You also want the equations to be numbered differently, namely to include the section count in the appendix. Therefore I use `etoolbox`'s `\appto` to also add this redefinition of the `equation` counter to `\appendix`, for that I use `\counterwithin`, which is in the LaTeX kernel since a few years (I don't remember since when, I think 2017, but am not sure).

Complete example of use:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% we also want to change the equation counter to display the current section
\appto\appendix{\counterwithin{equation}{section}}

\begin{document}
\section{A normal section}
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\appendix
\section{An appendix section}
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.